# How to convert numpy one dimensional array to Pandas Series or Dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, series, lmplot

I have spent quiet some time on what seems to be very easy thing. All I want is to convert a numpy array to a Series and then combine Series to make a dataframe. I have two numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

rooms = 2*np.random.rand(100, 1) + 3
price = 265 + 6*rooms + abs(np.random.randn(100, 1))
```

I wanted to convert rooms and price to series and then combine the  two series into a dataframe to make lmplot

So could any one tell me how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `ravel()` to convert the arrays to 1-d data:

```
pd.DataFrame({
     'rooms': rooms.ravel(),
    'price': price.ravel()
})
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but would it be possible to convert it to a series because it looks so obvious to do that. Why is it not possible or not first preference? Actually a bit curious to find out how to convert a one dimensional array to a Serious.

Comment: You can also do `pd.Series(rooms.ravel())` and then get the dataframe. I thought since you want a dataframe in the end, you might go through a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with passing the arrays directly to `pd.Series` is the dimensionality: `rooms` and `price` are 2d-array of shape `(100,1)` while `pd.Series` requires a 1d-array. To reshape them you can use different methods, one of which is `.squeeze()`, namely:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rooms = 2*np.random.rand(100, 1) + 3
price = 265 + 6*rooms + abs(np.random.randn(100, 1))

rooms_series = pd.Series(rooms.squeeze())
price_series = pd.Series(price.squeeze())
```

Now to go from series to dataframe you can do:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'rooms': rooms_series,
              'price': price_series})
```

Or directly from the numpy arrays:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'rooms': rooms.squeeze(),
              'price': price.squeeze()})
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. Yes that was the error I was getting although shape shows (rows x col) and probably means 100 rows and 1 column.